# Ref 2 Quest-ion..could-i-have-a-culture-where-stealing-is-not-wrong?

Tags: government, singularity

When we think of how a world or word, is created we realize that it sprung forth from an 'input output' system where we have been cultivated to depend on certain faculties such as the givens..air, water, food, shelter, warmth and being with someone, the real question here is....Where do we find there is a symbiotic nesscesity to take from something else? (Defined as stealing) If we are taking from something else personally and against a persons will, or is abusive, then we can see distortion here an we realize how this is seen as wrong..if we are taking because we are struggling financially and have no supportive people around us, and have no money for food or a space to rent then there is a difference here..tesco is not a person its a corporation that ironically takes from smaller business's, oil is based on taking from the planets resources without asking earths permission first..and look at the giants that have made their wealth there..surely it all can be measured against what is being taken, where, how and why? Not so black and white as..thats just wrong and thats just correct..We have to step back and take into consideration the deeper reasons!

Comment: Not really, or unlikely, any real world culture where the concepts of possessions & theft are recognised considers it wrong, a few cultures here & there haven't recognised ownership of much outside of the personal possessions you actually have with you however, which might have much the same effect?

Comment: Stealing is not "taking from something else". Stealing is *unauthorized* taking something from its *owner*. Note the keywords "unauthorized" and "owner".

Comment: Wen a rare female wasp assaults, intoxicates an impregnates a male cockroach to lay her egg in its body, 2 then gno her offspring is going to kill its unwilling father in its growth, Is there a difference between taking and stealing here? Where do we realize wen it is wrong and wen it is not? Authorized does not always mean that its the be all and end of all of what is acceptable,if a debt based system is already based on stealing an innocent at birth, an using its life as a commodidty and its justification to uphold economy, can we c y ppl may need to steal.

Comment: Can we see y people may struggle an may need to take or steal from a supermrket?..Can we c the corruption from the start..there are moral reasons and abusive wrong reasons for why!

Comment: You seem to be asking if stealing is *seen as* not wrong, but you seem to have your own definition of stealing and perhaps a somewhat nebulous definition of what constitutes "wrong". I'm voting to put your question on hold as unclear what you are asking, to give you time to [edit] it to make things clearer for us, without unhelpful answers cluttering the question in the meantime. Please take the [tour] and read-up in the [help] about how we work (as everyone does), and take note of how to approach [ask] questions. Welcome to the forum. Tell us about the world you are building. (From review)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not seem to be about building fictional worlds. This is not a general-purpose discussion board.

Comment: @o.m. _"does not seem to be about building fictional worlds"_ I think you may basing that too much on his response to comments (though they do appear to show a gaping disparity between his & my 'common frame of reference' (which is to say we appear to lack one), yours too I'm guessing), the question itself does appear to be about world building to me, it does seem to be far too broad & opinion based though.

Comment: The title is definitely an on-topic question: "Is it possible to have a culture where stealing is permitted?" The problem is that the body of the question is just an incoherent rant, and not an actual question.

Answer (score 2):

A number of cultures consider stealing from other members of the society to be wrong, but consider it entirely justified to steal from members of other societies.

For example, some of the Indian tribes and nations in the USA had warrior cultures where the only way for men to gain wealth and prestige was to raid other societies and steal from them.  As a result those groups tended to be in a state of perpetual low intensity war with all of their neighbors except for any tribes they happened to be allied with.